# Selenium Action clicking on every element before current

Tags: python, selenium

I've made a python code to find, click and type stuff into all inputs of type="text" in a page.

```py
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get("https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/checkout/")
    action = ActionChains(browser)

    inputs = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("input")

    for currentInput in inputs:
        if currentInput.get_attribute("type") == "text":
            action.move_to_element(currentInput).move_by_offset(5,5).click().perform()
            currentInput.send_keys("this is text thing")
        time.sleep(0.2)

    assert "No results found." not in browser.page_source
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.close()
```

What I expect is that it will click on the currentInput element, then type. What actually happens: it clicks on every previous input text element before proceeding to the send_keys event. For instance, if it's on the 3rd input, it'll click the 1st, 2nd, then 3rd and finally execute the next line. Is this a bug or did I do something wrong?

EDIT: I tried this on Firefox and it also happened there. I tried this same script on different pages and the result is the same, the action click().perform() runs through all previous elements of the same type before reaching the actual current one. These are the pages so anyone else can test, too:
https://sites.uwm.edu/mdisc/forum-signup/ ;
https://www.createaforum.com/free-forum.php

Comment: not sure what's happening there, but you shouldn't need the click.  send_keys will scroll the element into view, focus if necessary, and type.

Comment: i know the click is not neccessary, but it's something I've noticed and now I want to know what's going on. Also, I'm using this type of click because element.click() can fail with "element click intercepted exception"

Comment: it's possible the quirk has something to do with the intercepting event handler.  What element is retrieving the click first?  (it should be listed in that exception...)

Comment: I have tested with other pages, so it's not a problem with that specific page. The element intercept actually happens with the radio buttons of the page in the code, a label that's on top of the input

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by instantiating the action every time I was going to click, like this:

```
actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.MoveToElement(elementLocator).Click().Perform();
```